# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases a new-style class can't have only classic bases

Tags: python, oop, typeerror, new-style-class

A collection of classes defined as:

```python
class A():
    @staticmethod
    def call():
        print('a')

class C(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'somename'

class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = C

    @staticmethod
    def call():
        print('b')

    def boundcall(self):
        print('bound')
```

When run, gives this error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    a new-style class can't have only classic bases
```

I need the metaclass (I think) to have a known string representation of B in my code. Reason for having that is beside the point but it'll greatly help with future updates.

So assuming I need C to be the metaclass of B and B will be a subclass of A can someone tell me what is going wrong here and how I might change what I'm doing to remove the error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
class A():
```

It should be:

```
class A(object):
```

That way, you make A a new style class. The empty parens make no sense whatsoever, and still, I keep seeing them on stackoverflow and everywhere. Why, oh why?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I tried depreciating the version of the package. It worked !

Second trial, this was there in python 2 due to version issues. Upgrade your code to python3. It works.