# Python 2: create abstract base class inheriting from HTMLParser

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, html-parsing, abc

I have been working with HTML parsers in my latest Python 2 project (2.7.12). I want to create a single base class from which all of my HTML parser subclasses can inherit. However, I'd also like this base class (which inherits from `HTMLParser`) to be an abstract base class.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import abc
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

parser = MyParser()
```

However, when I attempt to run this file, I receive the following error (with stack trace):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sandbox.py", line 7, in <module>
    class MyParser(HTMLParser):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.py", line 87, in __new__
    cls = super(ABCMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    a new-style class can't have only classic bases
```

I've already Googled plenty for answers, finding SO posts like [TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases a new-style class can't have only classic bases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677163/typeerror-error-when-calling-the-metaclass-bases-a-new-style-class-cant-have-o). However, that particular post deals with new-style classes that I can create, and I haven't found any other source which describes my particular case (*i.e.* an abstract class inheriting from a class in the Python stdlib).

My suspicion is that the `HTMLParser` class provided by Python 2.7 is not a new-style class itself. If this is the issue, is there anything I can do about it? Does the `abc` module provide any means of achieving this kind of configuration?

Thanks,
Caleb